# is it possible to represent SQL RDB in XML?

Tags: sql, xml, key, relational-database, constraints

Is it possible to represent a SQL Relational Database in XML?

That is, how would XML handle the primary key -> foriegn key relationships?

Or is it the case that XML can only represent the data in a single table?

If it is possible, what would you do in the case of a table having more than one foreign key?  Which table is the parent in the hierarchical nesting since more than one other table holds the primary keys?

Comment: You should probably look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765381/db-or-xml-question or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/966901/modeling-xml-vs-relational-database

Comment: A .NET DataSet is an in-memory representation of a relational database. It serializes to XML, complete with the schema.

Comment: @Conrad Fix. Shoot. I did a bit of poking around on the site, but some how missed that page.  Thank you though, this looks like it should answer my questions. :)